# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_17 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 121]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a recurrent neural network using the NSL-KDD dataset. when I run the code below I keep getting the **ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_17 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 121]**. I can't figure out why, I might have something to do with the input shape? I am not sure as I am still new to python. I have done all the data pre processing as well if that helps.

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM, SimpleRNN, GRU
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import callbacks
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, CSVLogger
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

```
print (X_train.shape),(y_train2.shape)
(125973, 121)
(None, (125973,))
```

```
batch_size = 99
epcochs = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10,batch_input_shape =(None, 99, 1), return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam() , metrics=['accuarcy'])
fit=model.fit(X_train, y_train2, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_test, y_test2))
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test1)
print("\nLoss: %.2f, Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (loss, accuracy*100))
y_pred = model>predict_classes(X_test)
```

Comment: `batch_input_shape =(None, 99, 1)` but your first input is none. Also it is hard to tell something without knowing the shapes of x_train and y_train.

Comment: added it above, not sure why the y_train2 has a bit with no values

Comment: What operations did you perform on y_train?

Comment: I done this for the y_train2    `y_test2 = test_target2.astype('category').cat.codes`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
numpy.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0)
```